How to get Debt Ratio of DeltaPrime Account?
I'm going to create a C# application to track my positions in De-Fi protocols. I'm going to use Nethereum library to deal with Smart Contracts.
I'm new to the Blockchain world. However, I've already successfully integrated with the Beefy project.
Now, in my second application, I'm trying to get/calculate Debt Ratio of my DeltaPrime account. For example, how Rabby Wallet does this:

I've checked DeltaPrimes Contarct list https://docs.deltaprime.io/developers/contracts and the source code of Rabby Wallet and did find the code/APIs that can help me.
How do the projects like Rabby such integrations? Should I contact the DeltaPrime Team and ask them which APIs should I use, or can I do this with myself?


How do the projects like Rabby such integrations?

Rabby is run by Debank and they have one of the largest proprietary blockchain data indexer. They index all the data, of all protocols, through painfully many manual integrations. However this knowledge is proprietary to Debank and it's unlike they will share it with you.

Should I contact the DeltaPrime Team and ask them which APIs should I use, or can I do this with myself?

Yes, it is unlikely no one can help you on a generic discussion forum for a question that is specific to one commercial product.
Generally all products should do their own support, and not to outsource it to volunteers of other communities.
